# directory not created from puppetmaster

Tags: puppet

I am struggling to create a directory on the client from the puppetmaster.
I am using a mine module called push_file and got this structure

```
 /etc/puppet/modules/create_dir/
└── manifests
    ├── init.pp
    └── site.pp
```

in init.pp I've got

```
class push_file {
  file { "/tmp/puppet_dir":
    ensure => "directory",
  }
}
```

instead in site.pp I've got this

```
node default {
}

node apply_module {
  include push_file
}

node 'my_node' inherits apply_module {
}
```

from the client I run

```
puppet agent   --server=my_puppet_master  --debug  --onetime
```

and the log tells me that the transaction have been applied on the client and this is the result

```
Finishing transaction 70182904491460
Using cached certificate for ca
Using cached certificate for puppet_client_server
Ignoring --listen on onetime run
Finishing transaction 70182903618660
Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Using cached certificate for ca
Using cached certificate for puppet_client_server
Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml dot pson raw yaml; using pson
Caching catalog for puppet_client_server
Creating default schedules
Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Applying configuration version '1365504714'
Finishing transaction 70182902275900
Storing state
Stored state in 0.00 seconds
Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds
```

but the directory is not been created.
On the client the puppet version is 2.6.2-5
instead on the node master is 2.6.2-5
Both the machine are debian 6.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got where the **problems are**
the files

- site.pp
- nodes.pp

need to go under the puppetmaster's **manifest**  directory and **not** under the module's manifest directory.
**The below explanation is just a reminder for me and for somebody else who could have problems to push the file to the client.**

 If the triple slash in the source directive is not expanded from puppet, I mean this one,

```
source => 'puppet:///blahblah/bla',
```

and you get this kind of error **on the puppet client**

> Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from source(s) puppet:///files/another_test at /etc/puppet/modules/push_file/manifests/init.pp:11

**could** mean that your fileserver.conf got the wrong files directory, so
**check your fileserver.conf under the puppet folder** . Here there is an example

```
$cat /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf
[files]
path /etc/puppet/modules/files
allow *
```

Be careful if the last line (in my case) allow * is commented.
If yes you could have a permission problem and the puppet agent is not allowed to get the file from the master. You could receive a error like this one

> Could not evaluate: **Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on** /file_metadata/files/another_test Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///files/another_test: **Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on** /file_metadata/files/another_test at /etc/puppet/modules/push_file/manifests/init.pp:11

The most important things related to the previous error are that one highlighted in bold. the other are depending in the way that you configured your system.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define the node by it's fully qualified domain name. On your node, try:
  $ hostname -f

Use the output instead of **my_node** in your node site.pp.

Comment: my_node is just an indicator for not put the real domain name here on serverfalut.In site.pp there is the real domain name.